# SSIS Connection Manager - retry connection after failed attempt

Tags: ssis, ssis-connection-manager

I am wondering if there is a property from the connection manager or a straight forward way to retry the connection in case of timeout.

I am experiencing a random connection error when trying to connect to a webservice. I've checked that if I program a set of consecutive jobs to execute the package the connection works the 90% of the times, and I have not found a pattern neither the error message helps.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The possibilities i found are : configure the job step to retry (it would reiniciate the full package) or try with SSIS Breakpoints. Anyway finally I didn't use non of them because my problem solved increasing the timeout from the connection Manager